# Convert exact Sys.time() output to string / character in R?

Tags: r

How can we get the exact printed output of `Sys.time()` (e.g. `"2020-01-14 17:21:31 AEDT"`) as a string / character vector?

#### Background

The output of my `Sys.time()` is

```
[1] "2020-01-14 17:21:31 AEDT"
```

the `dput()` of which is

```
structure(1578982891.74164, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
```

In the console, it looks like it might be of `class` `character`, but as we can see from the `dput` (or by calling `class()`) it isn't

```
structure(1578982891.74164, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")) %>% class()
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

The exact output I am after is `"2020-01-14 17:21:31 AEDT"`, where `"2020-01-14 17:21:31 AEDT" %>% class` is `character`.

Also note: I would like to **not** use external packages for this

#### What I've tried so far

The obvious thing to try, `Sys.time() %>% as.character`, removes the characters at the end (`AEDT` in this case), which is **not** not desired here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option would be to use `format()`, which can take `Sys.time()` as input and generate a character output:

```
format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")

[1] "2020-01-14 07:40:06 CET"
```

Answer (score 6):

Tim gives the canonical answer -- you should know of & be familiar with `format`'s method for `Date` and `POSIXt` classes. Be sure to read `?strptime` regularly.

Note that `as.character(Sys.time())` will use the `POSIXt` method of `as.character`, which is actually just a simple wrapper for `format`:

```
print(as.character.POSIXt)
# function (x, ...) 
# format(x, ...)
# <bytecode: 0x7fbb67f28b20>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

So you could actually use `as.character` if that feels more natural to you; the easiest way would be to simply add `usetz = TRUE`:

```
as.character(Sys.time(), usetz = TRUE)
# [1] "2020-01-14 15:22:12 +08"
```

You can also use the `tz` argument for finer control over the time zone:

```
as.character(Sys.time(), tz = 'Asia/Jakarta', usetz = TRUE)
# [1] "2020-01-14 14:25:47 WIB"
```

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. I am changing my schedule for reading `?strptime` from 'never' to 'at least annually' :-)